# CSS3 transform property scale, text blurry on hover

Tags: css, scaletransform

I am testing a simple CSS3 scale on hover but text appears blurry for a second or something. the biggest issue is in firefox

here is a simple code

https://jsfiddle.net/u0jq9xk1/3/

I also tried to add the code below but it did not work

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
```

I know this is simple, but is it possible to sort it out or that;s some sort of bug ?

Comment: Works fine on Chromium, seems like a browser issue.

Comment: yes it's almost normal in chrome, though in firefox and edge the issue is kinda annoying

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work fine for me on Firefox. What OS do you use?

Comment: For me it works good on both firefox and chrome..

Comment: Do you have any other devices you can test the issue in?

Answer (score 0):

Can you test if this works for you

-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;